# Is it better to give an NSMutableArray or to create an NSArray from it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

This is a question that's been bothering me for a while.

I want to send some data in an NSArray to a viewController, and sometimes I need to create a NSMutableArray and populate it element by element.

If I send it to the viewController, it will be useless, as it only needs to read the array. So I'm wondering if it's more expensive to send an NSMutableArray, or to create a (maybe?) more lightweight NSArray, with the cost of memory allocation, and releasing the (maybe?) heavier NSMutableArray.

By the way, I know it's over optimization, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This has nothing to do with optimization.

(Or, very very little and only in uncommon cases)

It has everything to do with how defensive you want your code to be.

You can always return a subclass of whatever a method declares it's return type to be.  That *just works*.

The caller will only see it as a whatever the superclass is (`NSArray` in this case), unless they do something *exceptionally dangerous* by down casting to `NSMutableArray` and mutating the array.

When this happens, if you are still using that array as a backing store in your object, the caller will effectively be modifying your backing store out from under you.

By `return [[mutArray copy] autorelease];` you are ensuring that such silliness can never happen.  And, in fact, the AppKit suffered enough bugs from people casting and mucking with the arrays, that various methods have moved to `return [[mutArray copy] autorelease];`

There is also a threading implication;  read-only Foundation types are generally thread safe.  Read-write are not and *that includes reading while something else is writing*.  Thus, if you return a reference to a mutable array, you *cannot modify that array from another thread ever again* unless you absolutely know that all external references are gone (which, btw, isn't knowable without poor design).

The performance implication of immutable vs. mutable on copy is only very rarely an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can build it as an NSMutableArray but then send it as an NSArray.  This is valid, note the return type is NSArray but the object is NSMutableArray.  You can do this because a NSMutableArray **is a** NSArray, it is a subclass of NSArray.  In this example the caller gets an NSArray that they can't* modify.

```
-(NSArray*)buildArray
{
    NSMutableArray* mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];

    ... fill the array...

    return mutArray;
}
```

**not without casting*

Answer (score 2):

NSArray and NSMutableArray are both implemented with CFArray's so they should have the same performance at accessing element, if you took a look at the open-source-version but the closed-source you are using may differ (see comments).

The performance difference of using NSArray vs NSMutable array arises primarily when you copy the array. if you send -copy to an immutable array, it just bumps the retain count, but sending -copy to a mutable array will allocate heap memory.

Comment: Not true about the access patterns;  an immutable array will typically be faster because the internal data structures are fixed.  Mutable arrays are internally represented by data structures that make insertion relatively constant time.  I.e. internally, arrays are not just a single flat malloc() buffer.

Comment: 1. they have the same structure [CFArray.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-368.18/Collections.subproj/CFArray.c) 2. im not talking about insertion

Comment: Internally, mutable vs. immutable variants may be represented quite differently (and behavior of the version of CFArray on the system vs. the open source version may be different). That a mutable array is configured for insertion can impact retrieval speed. See http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/index.html. If I can get a hold of the source to the examples (link busted), I'll probably toss together graphs comparing mutable vs. immutable variants, if I have a moment. (Thanks, Peter, for pointing out my derping of the URL).

Answer (score 0):

If you are never going to use that particular array again, I would declare the return value to be an `NSArray` and just return the `NSMutableArray` you've just used to build it.

If you might use that array internally or return it later, I'd use `[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray]` to "downgrade" it.  Especially if you are creating a framework that others will be using.

Comment: Can you collaborate a little more detail on your two points above?  - "If you are never going to use that particular array again.." , "If you might use that array internally or return it later..."

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of the mutable array to make it an NSArray, it *is* an NSArray.

Comment: +1 it _is_ an NSArray, but if you are keeping the array internally to the object that is returning it, you want to convert it to non-mutable so that others don't change something from beneath you

Comment: @user "elaborate" - For example, if class Foo had a list of valid names, and a method that returned a list of three letter valid names, and I derived the 3-letter list, returning an NSArray, but also cached the array so I wouldn't have to re-derive it next time it is called, **I would change that NSMutableArray into a non-mutable array**.  Next time a valid name is added/remove, i flush the cache.  The immutable array can't (accidentally or maliciously) me manipulated by someone, and the cached value will be reused while it exists.

Comment: Except that passing a mutable array is only a problem if the receiver treats it as a mutable array. If it expects an immutable array, it should not attempt to mutate it. If it expects a mutable array, (1) it's worth re-examining why, and in the meantime, (2) why would you pass it anything else?